# the center of a simple ring is either $0$ or a field

Tags: ring-theory

The definition for a simple ring:

> A ring $R $ is said to be simple if $R^{2} \neq 0$ and $0$ and $ R $ are the only ideals
>   of $R$.

The definition for center of a ring:

> The *center* of $R$ is the subset $C(R) = \{x\in R \mid xr = rx , \forall r\in R\}$.

my question is: 
is the center of a simple ring  either $0$ or a field. In particular, a
commutative simple ring is thus necessarily a field.

Comment: Is there any reason to think that a subring of a simple ring is a simple ring?

Comment: A commutative simple ring is indeed a field, however. You'd just need to prove that if $R$ is simple then $C(R)$ is simple, which, at first glance, doesn't seem obvious.

Comment: And what exactly is meant by $R^2\neq 0$? Initially, I took it as meaning $rs\neq 0$ for some $r,s\in R$. But that's true if $R$ has an identity. So do your rings possible not have identities? Or do you mean something else by $R^2\neq 0$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, in the theory of simple rings without identity, that is a standard regularity condition to rule out degenerate cases where the multiplication is all zero. That is why [Smoktunowicz's example](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1081/AGB-120006478?journalCode=lagb20) of a simple nil algebra was so hard to come by.  Another regularity condition you see is $R^2=R$....

Comment: Is $R^2\neq 0$ equivalent to $R^2=R$ in this case? Not obvious - it would be true if $R^2$ was an ideal, but it is not obviously closed under addition. @rschwieb

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  a question is what is meant by $R^2$.  It could be an ideal if $R^2 = \{ \sum st \mid s, t \in R \}$.  Do you mean $R^2 = \{st   \mid st \in R \}$?

Comment: @rschwieb:  I would love to see your example but your link leads to a place which seems to require further permissions.  Any other places to look?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If the pairwise products are nonzero, the ideal product is nonzero. If the ideal product is nonzero, the pairwise products are nonzero. So it seems it doesn't matter how one interprets it.

Comment: @RobertLewis I had to obtain a copy via the library. I don't know of any place where the example is explained entirely with free access.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, a commutative simple ring is a field, but you need to show it has an identity.

Proof: Pick $x\neq 0$ from $R$ so that $xR\neq 0$. This is true since $R^2\neq 0$.

Since $xR$ is an ideal in $R$ and $xR\neq 0$, by simplicity, $xR=R.$

In particular, there is an $e\in R$ so that $xe=x$. But then for each $r\in R=xR$, we have $r=xr'$ for some $r'\in R$, and then $re=xr'e=xer'=xr'=r.$ So $e$ is a multiplicative identity of $R$.

Then the rest of your proof follows. For any non-zero $x\in R$, $x\in xR$, so $xR$ is a non-zero ideal, so $xR=R$ and hence $e\in xR$, so $x$ has a multiplicative inverse.

You can only conclude that $C(R)$ is a field if you know that $C(R)$ is simple. It is not generally true that if $S$ is a subring of a simple ring $R$, then $S$ is simple. (For example, $R=\mathbb Q, S=\mathbb Z$.) So you'd need some proof that if $R$ is simple then $C(R)$ is simple.

I haven't found that proof, but I haven't found a counter-example, either.

If $x\in C(R)$ and $xC(R)\neq 0$ and $xC(R)\neq C(R)$, then we have that $xR\supseteq xC(R)\neq 0$, so $xR=R$ by $R$'s simplicity. If $xC(R)\neq C(R)$, then some element of $y\in C(R)$ can be written as $y=xr$ for some $r\in R\setminus C(R).$ Now, given $a\in R$. you have that $a=xa'$ for some $a'$ so that:

$$ar = xb'r=b'xr=b'y=yb'=rx'b=ra$$

So we get that $y\in C(R)$, which is a contradiction.

We are left with the case where $C(R)$ is not simple because $C(R)^2=0$. I wonder if it is possible to find such a case. Is it perhaps possible that $C(R)=0$? Certainly not when $R$ has an identity. When $R$ is a simple ring with identity, then $C(R)$ is definitely a field.

Comment: I have a few questions about your argument(s).  I'm with you when you say $\exists x \mid xR \ne 0$ (first line)..  I agree that $xR$ is a *right* ideal in $R$.  However, my understanding of "simple ring" is one whose only *two-sided* ideals are $0$ and $R$.  So one needs a stronger hypothesis on $R$ than my understanding of *simple* (which, for better or for worse, agrees with widipedia's::  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_ring).  Of course, if one rules out *one-sided* ideals other than $0$ or $R$, your argument flies.    Am I missing something here?

Comment: We are assuming $R$ is a commutative simple ring, so no difference between right ideals and ideals. @RobertLewis

Comment: Yes, I see that if $R$ is assumed commutative, your argument files.

Comment: I was wondering if the conclusion $C(R)$ is a field holds under the problem hypothesis in the general case of not-necessarily-commutative $R$.

Comment: By the way I upvoted your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure about the general $C(R)$ case. I haven't found a proof that $C(R)^2\neq 0$. But I have shown that there are no other ideals in $C(R)$ other than $0$ and $C(R)$. More strongly, we can show that if $C(R)$ is not a field, then $C(R)R=0$.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but recently I was wondering the same thing.

By Thomas Andrews' arguments, it remains to show that if a ring $R$ is simple and non-unital, its centre is zero. To obtain a contradiction, assume there exists a non-zero central element $z\in R$. As $R^2 \neq \{0\}$, note that $zR$ is a non-zero ideal of $R$. Otherwise we would have $zR=Rz=\{0\}$, so $\mathbb{Z}z:=\{nz: \, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ would be a non-zero ideal of $R$. As $R$ is simple, this forces $\mathbb{Z}z=R$. But then $R^2=\{0\}$; a contradiction.

Hence, as $zR$ is a non-zero ideal of $R$, by simplicity of $R$ we have $zR=R$, so there is $e \in R$ such that $ze=z$. Then, since $zR=R$ and $z$ is central, it follows that $e$ is an identity in $R$; a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ in $\mathbb {Z(R)}$. Then $aR$ is two sided ideal of $\mathbb {R}$. So, $aR=R$. Hence  a is invertible  in $\mathbb {R}$, that is $ar=1$ for some $r$ in $\mathbb {R}$. Also, $r \in \mathbb {Z(R)}$ since $a$ in $\mathbb {Z(\mathbb {R})}$. Hence $\mathbb{Z(R)}$ is a field.